# Nested Select MySQL statements to LINQ

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

I'm trying to convert the following MySQL statement in to LINQ query format

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table1.id IN (SELECT c_id FROM table2 WHERE a_id IN (1, 49) GROUP BY c_id HAVING COUNT(*) = 2) ORDER BY name
```

Got as far as this, but I'm drawing a blank on how to handle the IN and 2nd SELECT statement

```
myItems = from c in table1
          let id = c.id
          where ????
          orderby c.name
          select c;
```

Would appreciate some guidance with this please

Comment: Are you using EF?

Comment: no, I'm not.  If it helps this is for a UWP app

Comment: Are you sure that query works, in your inner query you are selecting c_id but you are grouping by id? Is that a typo?

Comment: my bad... just edited, should've copied and pasted rather than typed from memory!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var ids=new[]{1,49};
var innerquery=table2.Where(e=>ids.Contains(e.a_id))
                     .GroupBy(e=>e.c_id)
                     .Where(g=>g.Count()==2)
                     .Select(g=>g.Key);

var  myItems = from c in table1
               where innerquery.Contains(c.id)
               orderby c.name
               select c;
```

First define your inner query,after the group by you will get a collection of `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>>` that represent a collection of objects that have a common key, filter the groups choosing only those where count==2, and select the keys of those groups. The second part is really easy to understand. I split the process in two queries to do it more readable, but you can merge both query in one.

Comment: Spot on! I assume it's a lot harder to do it all in one query?  Not that I'm too bothered as this way works fine thanks